# jQuery fancybox click function for dynamically added content not firing on iOS, iPhone, nor iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, click

Just add: `cursor: pointer` to your `<a>` link a problem solved!

---

In the following code, a fancybox link is dynamically clicked to open up a fancybox gallery. This works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox etc. However on iOS, ipad, iphone, etc, it does not.

```
$(document).on('click', '.item .img-link', function(){
    var $me = $(this),
        myTargetRel = $me.data('target'),
        $myTarget = $('#item-images a[rel=' + myTargetRel + ']');

    $myTarget.click();
});
```

How do I get this working for iOS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a known bug of iOS not responding to click events on `<a>` tags, check these links out:

[jquery.click() not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095868/jquery-click-not-working-in-ios)

[How to make my 'click' function work with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577906/how-to-make-my-click-function-work-with-ios)