# How to bind a click event in iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, click

I'm "just" trying to bind a click event to a `<button>` and make it work for Desktop (chrome, FF, ... ), android and iOS.

I tried a lot of stuff such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10577976/3636091) `cursor: pointer` which seemed to be the easiest and most effective but didn't work.

I also tried an `onclick=''` or `onclick='void(0)'` on the HTML element, a trick I've seen I don't even remember where ...

I tried with extern libraries such as [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to delete to 300ms wait after a click ... Doesn't work

And no more chance with [Pointer Events Polyfill](https://github.com/jquery/PEP) and binding with `pointerup` ...

I've run out of ideas ...

**My HTML :**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" onclick='' id="begin" class="btn andro btn-danger btnlg">
        <img src="img/icon.png" height="50px"> GO
        <img src="img/icon.png" height="50px">
    </button>
</div>
```

**My JS :**

```
  $(document).on('touchstart', '#begin', function() {
      // do things
  });
```

I tried of course to bind `touchstart` (even `touchend` !) instead of `click` and still doesn't work on iphones ...

The problem is : I don't have an iphone to test my stuff so I have to trust some friends who have an iOS device ... Do I have to change my code ... Or change my friends ? ^^

Comment: `I don't have an iphone to test my stuff` if you use Safari there's an option in the dev console to make it emulate an iPhone

Comment: Habe you tried removing the onclick attribute from your button element? My guess is that because it's just an empty string Safari on iPhone ignores any events on the button

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : I should try that thanks for the info :) .. Does it emulate a truly iOS device ? ...

@PatrickHund : I have to admit that I don't think I've tried to bind touchstart without `onclick=''` but if I use `touchstart` it won't trigger on Desktop or i'll have to sniff for user agent like here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34493059/3636091 or you know some workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo.... After a lot of searches and tries such as removing one by one libraries and commenting parts of the code...

I was able to find what was messing with the click ... It was because my bindings were encapsulated in a :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // My bindings here
});
```

and it seems like iOS don't like this ...

Just bind your click out of the ready function and it works... Hope it can help someone !