# CSS hover effect not working when hexagon shape changed to square

Tags: css, hover, responsive

I have a grid of hexagons that don't display hover effects when their shape is changed to squares. I am using the effects from this library https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover ( https://cdn.bootcss.com/hover.css/2.1.1/css/hover.css )
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers............................................................................................................................................................

```css
/* grid of hexagons */
.hex-background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hex-background .text {
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.hex-background:hover .text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 51%;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grid {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.grid li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
  padding-bottom: 20.78461%;
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.grid li:nth-child(2n) {
  margin: 0 1%;
}
.grid li:nth-child(10n+6),
.grid li:nth-child(10n+7),
.grid li:nth-child(10n+8),
.grid li:nth-child(10n+9),
.grid li:nth-child(10n+10) {
  margin-top: -4.5%;
  margin-bottom: -4.5%;
  -o-transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
.grid li .hexagon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  /*background images*/
}
.grid li .hexagon.img1 {
  background: url("https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5560/15235542331_fbe56a772e_b.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img1 .text {
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img1:hover .text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 51%;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img2 {
  background: url("https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7490/16150657349_cf9be4ce7e_b.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img2 .text {
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img2:hover .text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 51%;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img3 {
  background: url("https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5205/5262879347_26a831f439_b.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img3 .text {
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img3:hover .text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 51%;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grid li * {
  visibility: visible;
}
.grid li p {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    -o-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
  }
  .grid li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
  .grid li:nth-child(2n) {
    margin: 0 0%;
  }
  .grid li .hexagon {
    position: relative;
    top: none;
    left: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    -o-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+6),
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+7),
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+8),
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+9),
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+10) {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    -o-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .grid li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
}
/*hover effects*/
/*!
 * Hover.css (http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)
 * Version: 2.2.0
 * Author: Ian Lunn @IanLunn
 * Author URL: http://ianlunn.co.uk/
 * Github: https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover

 * Hover.css Copyright Ian Lunn 2017. Generated with LESS.
 */
/* Sweep To Right */
.hvr-sweep-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2693ff;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-right:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-right:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
/* Sweep To Bottom */
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2693ff;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
/* Radial Out */
.hvr-radial-out {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-radial-out:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2693ff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-radial-out:hover,
.hvr-radial-out:focus,
.hvr-radial-out:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-radial-out:hover:before,
.hvr-radial-out:focus:before,
.hvr-radial-out:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
/* Shutter Out Horizontal */
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2693ff;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover,
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus,
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover:before,
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus:before,
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/hover.css/2.1.1/css/hover.css">-->
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="grid">
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-sweep-to-right"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-radial-out"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-sweep-to-right"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-radial-out"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-sweep-to-right"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-radial-out"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-sweep-to-right"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-radial-out"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>

 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can only use `:hover` on mobile if you hold with your finger on the thing which have a `:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

I think hover does not works on mobile devices. Because :hover requires a pointer to activate.
[There are more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427447/does-css-hover-work-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: I mean it works until you rescale the window to <768 pixels, where the hexagons are displayed as a square.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:active` pseudo class for mobile insted of `:hover`

Also it's good to put `cursor: pointer;`

Keep in mind also this specific behaviour for iphone - [How to make my 'click' function work with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577906/how-to-make-my-click-function-work-with-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue. Its to do with the z-index of the background effect. For example for  `hvr-shutter-out-horizontal`, in the css class `.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:before { }` change the z-index to something like z-index: 5 instead of -1. Then in `.grid li .hexagon.img1 .text` change it to a higher z index like z-index:10 so the text is visible in front. Working solution here. Using this fix means you should be able to use any of the css hover effects in this library https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover

```css
/* grid of hexagons */

.grid {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.grid li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
  padding-bottom: 20.78461%;
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.grid li:nth-child(2n) {
  margin: 0 1%;
}
.grid li:nth-child(10n+6),
.grid li:nth-child(10n+7),
.grid li:nth-child(10n+8),
.grid li:nth-child(10n+9),
.grid li:nth-child(10n+10) {
  margin-top: -4.5%;
  margin-bottom: -4.5%;
  -o-transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: translateX(48%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
.grid li .hexagon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  /*background images*/
}
.grid li .hexagon.img1 {
  background: url("https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5560/15235542331_fbe56a772e_b.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img1 .text {
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
   z-index: 10;
 position: relative;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img1:hover .text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 51%;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img2 {
  background: url("https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7490/16150657349_cf9be4ce7e_b.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img2 .text {
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
   z-index: 10;
 position: relative;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img2:hover .text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 51%;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img3 {
  background: url("https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5205/5262879347_26a831f439_b.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
.grid li .hexagon.img3 .text {
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
   z-index: 10;
 position: relative;
}
.grid li .hexagon.img3:hover .text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 51%;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.grid li * {
  visibility: visible;
}
.grid li p {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    -o-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
  }
  .grid li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
  .grid li:nth-child(2n) {
    margin: 0 0%;
  }
  .grid li .hexagon {
    position: relative;
    top: none;
    left: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    -o-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+6),
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+7),
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+8),
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+9),
  .grid li:nth-child(10n+10) {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    -o-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .grid li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
}
/*hover effects*/
/*!
 * Hover.css (http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)
 * Version: 2.2.0
 * Author: Ian Lunn @IanLunn
 * Author URL: http://ianlunn.co.uk/
 * Github: https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover

 * Hover.css Copyright Ian Lunn 2017. Generated with LESS.
 */
/* Sweep To Right */
.hvr-sweep-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2693ff;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-right:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-right:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
/* Sweep To Bottom */
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2693ff;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
/* Radial Out */
.hvr-radial-out {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-radial-out:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2693ff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-radial-out:hover,
.hvr-radial-out:focus,
.hvr-radial-out:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-radial-out:hover:before,
.hvr-radial-out:focus:before,
.hvr-radial-out:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
/* Shutter Out Horizontal */
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2693ff;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover,
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus,
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover:before,
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus:before,
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/hover.css/2.1.1/css/hover.css">-->
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="grid">
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-sweep-to-right"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-radial-out"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-sweep-to-right"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-radial-out"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-sweep-to-right"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-radial-out"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img1 hvr-sweep-to-right"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img2 hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><div class="hexagon img3 hvr-radial-out"><div class="text">Hello World</div></div></a>
  </li>

 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```