# Why hammer.js swiping does not work for iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, css, hammer.js

I couldn't find a more direct way to ask people who are familiar with hammer.js so i'm posting here.

So i've been working on a web app with 8thwall using hammer.js for swiping/scrolling. i've been testing it on my samsung 10 and only now testing on the iphones. The swiping/scrolling has been working fine with my samsung 10 but it doesnt work at all with iphones that i could get my hands on. I've tried iphone 8plus, iphone xr, iphone 6s. Please advise on what i need to do. Thank you.

my codes :

```
 //SCROLLING FUNCTION
    AFRAME.registerComponent('scroll-lines', {
        init: function(){
            var container = document.getElementById("scrolling-container");
            var content = document.getElementById("button-collections");
            var hammer = new Hammer(container);

            var initialX = 0;
            var deltaX = 0;
            var offset = initialX + deltaX;

            hammer.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
                deltaX = ev.deltaX;
                offset = initialX + deltaX;

                container.scroll(-offset, 0);
            });

            Hammer.on(container, "mouseup", function(e) {
                initialX = offset;
            });
        }
    })

<!--SCROLLING BUTTONS-->
<!--IN ORDER FOR THESE TO BE DISPLAYED NEED TO STYLE THE Z-INDEX: 10. REFER style.css PAGE-->
<div id="scrolling-container">
    <div id="button-collections">
        <div id="box-all" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-seremban" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-klang" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-ampang" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-petaling" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-kj" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-ekspres" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-transit" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-monorail" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-kajang" class="cantap"></div>
        <div id="box-skypark" class="cantap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#scrolling-container{
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    top: 55%;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
}
#button-collections{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: horizontal;
   overflow: scroll;
   height: 150px;
   padding-top: 170px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

**UPDATE: I tried the suggestions below but they did not resolve the issue. I found that if i used var hammer = new Hammer(container); it works for android not iOS but if i use var hammer = new Hammer(content); it works for both but at the mouseup function i am not able to scroll to the end for both iOS and android. using panleft, panright, panend**

**UPDATE 2: So since hammerjs is sorta working on the iphone, my question is sort of answered. closed question. opened a new follow up question for current situation**

Answer (score 0):

Well are you sure you want to use pan? Pan is for dragging basically. Swipe is called `swipe` in hammer.js. It could be that on android the correct gesture is triggered, but not on iphone. If you move your finger fast, its a swipe, and won't be recognized as a pan. Also instead of `mouseup` you should use `panend` probably (because maybe android fires mouseup, and iphone doesn't).

Possible events with pan are:

- panstart
- panmove
- panend
- pancancel
- panleft
- panright
- panup
- pandown

Comment: So if i used `var hammer = new Hammer(container);` it works for android not iOS but if i use `var hammer = new Hammer(content);` it works for both but at the `mouseup` function i am not able to scroll to the end for both iOS and android. using panleft, panright, panend

Answer (score 0):

Try to use swipeleft and swiperight events instead of pan events.

Answer (score 0):

Without a `cursor` defined on the elements iOS does not fire the `mousedown` or `mouseup` client-side events which are needed for swipe. See [How to make my 'click' function work with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10577976/371).

Assign a class `ios-device` to your `<body>` when you detect iOS and use the following style.

```
body.ios-device {
    cursor: pointer !important; /* iOS click events don't fire without this! */
}
```

Comment: So if i used var hammer = new Hammer(container); it works for android not iOS but if i use var hammer = new Hammer(content); it works for both but at the mouseup function i am not able to scroll to the end for both iOS and android. using panleft, panright, panend